# how to get the account user ID using account phone number in telegram

Tags: python, bash, curl, telegram, telethon

I want to make a tool that get the account user ID using the account phone number.

is there a method give me the access to do this job?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get user entity with `get_entity`.

```
user = client.get_entity('+xxxxxxxxxxx') #xxx : phone number
```